# Associating additional products to be bought while buying a product in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am developing a magento shopping cart for selling some products. When the customer has chosen his product and wants to check out the product,  I also want him to select some associated products that he would like to add to his cart. This association I should be able to make in the magento admin panel.

A working example of this is on [this site](http://www.hirekogolf.com/hireko/orderportal/catalog_presentation/by_group/0/1853/0/0/0/0/0).

Here is a screenshot of the requirement:

http://content.screencast.com/users/wardogg/folders/Jing/media/540714aa-7e54-461c-b09d-f1cba4513eff/2012-09-06_1612.png

I am using Magento shopping cart for my application. I would like to know if there is an existing extension that allows us to do this or if I will have to code something on my own.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Built in already. RTFM:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-product-relations

> Cross-Sells Cross-sells display after a product has already been added
>   to the shopping cart.  In this design package, three products are
>   randomly picked from the products that are marked as cross-sells of
>   all the products in the shopping cart.  To add cross-sell items to a
>   product:  Log in to the Magento admin Navigate to Catalog -> Manage
>   Products Find the product you want to add cross-sells to Select and
>   edit this product Select the Cross-sells tab From the products grid
>   that appears, check any products you’d like to mark as cross-sells
>   (press “Reset Filter” to see all products) Once a product has been
>   checked, the “Position” field opens up.  This determines the sort
>   order of the cross-sells in the shopping cart.  If you have multiple
>   products in the cart they are randomly selected, so the sort order
>   will not take effect. Press “Save” In the front-end, add the product
>   you just edited to the shopping cart.

Clearly you need to style up your suggested products and how and when they appear in the customer journey. It may take work to get it right but it can all be done.